# How to convert a htmldivelement Object into a JSX/React Element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

I've been trying to integrate 2 existing web applications with each other. However, one is using React with JSX, while the other is using simple JavaScript and HTML. As such, I am working with both DOM elements and JSX.

**My question is**, is there any way I can convert DOM objects into React elements? This is because when I try to use ReactDOM's `.render()` method to update the React page with a DOM object,  [I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10qYT.png).

**P.S.** I am aware of that react has the attribute `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and there exists a NPM package named react-html-parser. However, I'm looking for a more secure option that won't open my web application to XXS attacks.

Comment: My apologies for attaching the wronng screenshot. The error I receive is "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library named Dompurify. You can use it to sanitize your html first then use react-html-parser to convert it to jsx

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import parse from "html-react-parser";

const cleanHtmlString = DOMPurify.sanitize(htmlString,
{ USE_PROFILES: { html: true } });

parse(cleanHtmlString);//will convert it to jsx
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I do have one question though. What is there stopping a malicious actor from just manipulating the .js files in my application through the browser to remove the sanitation?

Comment: @SoftWorker you're welcome :)
I don't know too much about security but I think that xss attacks use your text input fields to inject javascript code into your website so I think the only way to prevent these attacks is to avoid or be careful with dangerouslySetInnerHTML and do enough form validation and sanitization when needed. 

You should check out how to prevent other types of attacks as well ;)